# Unity 4.6: why Image object doesn't stretch all sides of canvas

Tags: unity

I insert a canvas, after that, I insert an image at center. Then, I want to stretch this image over this canvas, so I choose last option as below:

[image]

But the image doesn't stretch to fit the canvas, as you see: (in fact, image object doesn't change anything)

[image]

Please tell me how to make this image stretches over the canvas.

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the top notification says, in order to achieve the desired effect, you need to hold down **ALT** and **SHIFT** when clicking the stretch icon.

[image]

More info: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RectTransform.html
Video: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/rect-transform

Comment: too simple :D thanks :) I don't know why does Unity make us to do this ? If I choose without press Shift and Alt, are there any effects for this behavior ?

Comment: It is that way because maybe sometimes you want to set only the Anchor, or the Anchor and Pivot only.

Comment: To put that in a bit more context, Unity assumes that the way you have it looking on screen right now is the way you *want* it to look, so when you change an anchor setting, by default it updates the other settings to compensate & maintain the current appearance (rather than force you to go back and adjust those manually). This helps if you wanted to lay out some UI visually without thinking of stretching behaviour first, and then want to update the finished layout to stretch correctly. For other cases, they provided these modifier keys.